# How to share lambda function across all methods in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, lambda

I have a lambda like this:

```rb
class MyClass
   def test
      to_cross = lambda do |m, x| # Just a dummy example
        return m * x
      end
      
      to_cross.call(7, 9)
   end
   
   def another_method
      to_cross = lambda do |m, x| # Just a dummy example
        return m * x
      end
   
      to_cross.call(2, 5)
   end
end
```

However, I want to use this lambda among all methods in that class. How can I make it class-wide?

I tried something like this:

```rb
class MyClass

   # Define in class
   to_cross = lambda do |m, x| # Just a dummy example
     return m * x
   end

   def test
      to_cross.call(2, 5)
   end

   def another_method
      to_cross.call(2, 5)
   end
end
```

I got:

```rb
undefined local variable or method `to_cross' for #<MyClass:0x0000564193f4e748>
```

What are my options? How can I use this lambda across all methods in `MyClass`? What are the options and what are their cons/pros?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use Instance Variables

You can store your Proc or lambda as an instance variable. You can then access that variable from any method in your class. For example:

```
class MyClass
   def initialize
     # make the lambda accessible throughout the
     # class as an instance variable
     @to_cross = ->(m, x) { m * x }
   end

   def test
     @to_cross.call 7, 9
   end

   def another_method
     @to_cross.call 2, 5
   end
end

klass = MyClass.new
klass.test            #=> 63
klass.another_method  #=> 10
```

The main point is to store the lambda in a scope that makes it accessible from other methods within your instance or class, or to pass the lambda around explicitly as an argument. If you store it as a variable, the choice of instance variable, class variable, or class/module constant will depend on a variety of factors, but instance variables will more often be the right generic choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access a class local variable from within the class method. In the same way

```
x=5
def f
  x
end
```

does not work; you are getting a syntax error, when calling `f`, because `x` is not defined.

Technically speaking, you can use instance variables in your class (`@to_cross`) or class variables (`@@to_cross`) or even global variables (`$to_cross`), though the cases for a good use of the latter are rare. You could also use a constant (`To_cross`), if you don't plan to reassign it (but then, of course, we wonder, why you have a variable assigned from a lambda, and not simply a class method).

Before deciding how to model this lamda, I would therefore think about

- where and how you are going to call it from, and
- from where are you going to modify this variable

In your case, you just say that you want to call it from every instance method, and this means that you should not use an variable with a lambda, but a (perhaps private) instance method, or a class method. Since the `to_cross` in your example does not seem to access any other instance methods, nor instance variables, maybe a class method would be more appropriate:

```
def self.to_cross(m,x)
  m*x
end
```

which you then would call as

```
def another_method
   self.class.to_cross.call(2, 5)
end
```